# Durandal routes to modules across domains

Tags: requirejs, durandal, hottowel

How can I define routes to modules sitting on different domains (or subdomains)?

The idea is to componentize the UI and deploy to multiple Azure roles:

- Chrome/Shell app that holds navigation and branding
- Feature Area 1 (say Ordering pages)
- Feature Area 2 (all the User Management stuff)

The chrome/shell nav would hold links across the feature areas and pull it all together.  I've done a bunch of trial/error and searching but haven't made much progress (other than learning how routing and require.js work).  Appreciate any help.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered creating multiple SPAs, one for each area?

Comment: Then we're duplicating the logic in the chrome/shell app.  That's our fallback but would like to not have to deal with the duplication if at all possible.

Comment: Out of interest what would be the advantage? Wouldnt concurrent background workers for the Backend be of more usw for performance increase?

Comment: It's not a performance thing, it's for separation of feature areas so we can release chunks of the system independently, guarantee a change to one area won't break another, etc...

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way to do it:

1. Don't call router.makeRelative()
2. Specify the full route (ex. http://x.com/test/App/viewmodels/test.js) in routes.push()
3. In the require.config have userXhr: return true
4. You probably needs to enable CORS on the server side

*Note:* Durandal did want to have the view convention use test.js.html, but I expect you could fix that by extending the router.

Depending on how you optimize/minimize/aggregate your javascript this may not work since it relies on Require.